# FRANCE neon transformer

Tags: transformer

I have an older FRANCE PG-1 Series neon sign transformer. It is a type that contains a SCGFP potted module in top compartment of transformer. There are a number of leads originating from the potted transformer, which I am trying to identify.

3 of the leads, black, white and green,  ring out as extensions from the input power posts. This is the 120 VAC supply to the unit.

There are 4 remaining leads:

- (1) blue
- (1) blue with white stripe
- (1) orange
- (1) orange with black stripe

Can anyone tell me what these 4 leads do and how to reconnect them, once the SCGFP potted module is removed?

Comment: Why the shouting in the title? A photo would say more than a thousand words here.

Comment: can you provide any further information?  it is hard to answer the question without more information on your setup, what you are trying to achieve and detailed information (pics / schematics / links etc) to the part in question.  I tried googling the above numbers / part number unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Locate a datasheet that represents your GF circuit.

https://a89b8e4143ca50438f09-7c1706ba3fabeeda794725d88e4f5e57.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/spec_sheets/files/000/018/604/original/france-15030p5g2ue-instructions.pdf?1442934472

The high R coils will be secondary.